# Oxygen in Asteroid Survival?

Tags: space-engineers

I am new to the game and started a survival game with the rescue ship (Asteroids). I believe it has a Oxygen generator as it shows in the menu of ship components but I cannot seem to regenerate oxygen levels. I read that I need to connect it through a surveyor belt but shouldn't this be already setup in this ship?

Oxygen levels go down quick and I'm still just 5 minutes in the game, what should I do exactly to maintain oxygen? Do I have to rush certain items and build it myself? I never even placed a block... :).

Answer (score 4):

The oxygen generator creates oxygen from [**Ice**](http://www.spaceengineerswiki.com/Ice). Ice is a white-blueish mineral (can sometimes be confused with silver or platinum) which can be mined from some asteroids with your drill tool.

1. Press "G" to open the toolbar config screen
2. click on "Character Tools"
3. Drag the "Hand Drill" to a free slot in your toolbar.
4. Look for an asteroid with ice (only a few of them have it)
5. Press the corresponding number key to equip your drill.
6. fly to the ice deposit - HUD icons denoting mineral deposits should appear when you approach an asteroid while having the drill equipped.
7. left-click with your drill equipped to mine the ice,
8. pick up the lumps of ice which float away
9. fly to your oxygen generator and open its inventory by approaching one its terminals (the yellow squares which light up when you point at them from close by) and pressing "K"
10. drag&drop the ice from your personal inventory into the oxygen generators inventory

It will then start to produce oxygen which is stored in any oxygen tanks connected to it by conveyor tubes.

An alternative way to produce oxygen are [oxygen farms](http://www.spaceengineerswiki.com/Oxygen_Farm) which only require sunlight to work, but you need a lot of them (at least two to stay alive, under the condition that you don't waste any oxygen).

An asteroid with ice:
[image: An asteroid with ice]

A lump of ice extracted with the drill tool:
[image: A lump of ice extracted with the drill tool]

Filling an oxygen generator with ice:
[image: Filling an oxygen generator with ice]

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest and fastest way to regain oxygen is oxygen bottles; you will use them from inventory when you're below 30% oxygen automatically. If your ship didn't come with any, they can be made at an assembler from the tools category. They can be refilled at an oxy generator or tank as long as there is ice in the generator or oxygen in the tank.

If the oxygen generator is connected via conveyors to a cockpit you will regain oxygen when in the cockpit; at least one of the respawn ships comes with this set up already. You can also connect it to a medical room and get refilled while touching the panel.